# Date Input | adding dash after the date

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to add the - after the second digit(date) on keypress for the date. Suppose if the user types the today s date as 24 after which - should be added and then after typing month "11" it should type - automatically.

Similarly, while backspacing/removing the character, dash to be removed.

Pattern : `pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}"`

#### Function

```js
onChangeText = (text) => {
  
  text = text
    .replace(/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/g, '')
    .replace(/^(\d\d\d\d)(\d)$/g, '$1-$2')
    .replace(/^(\d\d\d\d\-\d\d)(\d+)$/g, '$1-$2')
    .replace(/[^\d\-]/g, '')

}
```

Comment: Well, I came to answer the question, then found myself humbled by this syntax, which is unfamiliar to me. `const { getDate } = this.props` - could you kindly explain what that does or provide an MDN reference?

Comment: I am using react-native in my project, this.props are the property passed from the parent components. Updating the code

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Sure, but I ws susprised it was considered valid JS syntax. Obviously a feature that I am currently unaware of. With my perhaps data JS knowledge, `{ foo } = bar` would definitely not be valid syntax.

Comment: That's valid syntax in ES6 and It's called object destruction. Please visit the link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 0):

here is you can do something like this, but you need first declare a variable and get the value after the regx. when you're done with regx then declare a varible and store the value in it then apply below logic!

**Example**
here we go!

```js
let data = '123233';

let newData = ''; // declare the golbal variable to put dash

for ( let str = 0; data.length > str; ++str )
  {
    if( str % 2 === 0 && str !== 0) // finding even number and also zero
      newData += '-',newData += data[str - 0];
    else
      newData += data[str]
  }

console.log(newData)
```

apply this logic in your code, i hope you will get your expection!

Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for on a keypress. As soon as 12 is typed. Dash to be added after that

Comment: no matter, put this code inside onpress function, it'll work the same as you expect. and you can also share you code with us somewhere, codepen, jsbin, or..!